# Interacting with WebView in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-view

I have a webview and onCLick of a thumbanail in the webview I need to show a gallery from Android activity. How do I achieve this? Also can I get a sample code/app as how to interact with the WebView and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

You need to create a class in your Android code and pass it to the webview using `WebView.addJavascriptInterface`